# UI Automation - Select object based on multiple Identifiers

Tags: microsoft-ui-automation

I am new to this. I am using UI Automation to automate my application.  Is there a way to identify element based on multiple identifier.
currently the below syntax only able to identify based on one identifier.

```
AutomationElement okbtn = dialogbox.FindFirst(TreeScope.Children, new PropertyCondition(AutomationElement.NameProperty, "OK"));
```

I would like to take identify element by both NameProperty and ControlTypeProperty.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
        Condition cMenuItem = new AndCondition(
            new PropertyCondition(AutomationElement.LocalizedControlTypeProperty,"text"),
            new PropertyCondition(AutomationElement.NameProperty,"Appointment"));

        AutomationElement aeMenuItem = aeTaskMenu.FindFirst(TreeScope.Descendants, cMenuItem);
```